# Extract value from array in Spark

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extract a value from an array in SparkSQL, but getting the error below:

Example column

```
customer_details  
{"original_customer_id":"ch_382820","first_customer_id":"ch_343948"}
```

I am using this code:

```scala
get_json_object(customer_details, '$.original_customer_id') as customer_id
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
error: invalid string interpolation $., expected: $$, $identifier or ${expression}
       spark.sql(s"""

error: unclosed character literal (or use " not ' for string literal)
           get_json_object(customer_details, '$.original_customer_id') as customer_id,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the following worked:

```scala
val df = Seq("{'original_customer_id':'ch_382820','first_customer_id':'ch_343948'}").toDF("customer_details")
df.show(truncate=false)
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |customer_details                                                    |
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |{'original_customer_id':'ch_382820','first_customer_id':'ch_343948'}|
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------+

df.selectExpr("get_json_object(customer_details, '$.original_customer_id') as customer_id").show()
// +-----------+
// |customer_id|
// +-----------+
// |  ch_382820|
// +-----------+
```

As requested, this is Spark SQL version:

```sql
select get_json_object(customer_details, '$.original_customer_id') as customer_id
from df
```

```scala
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql(
    """
    select get_json_object(customer_details, '$.original_customer_id') as customer_id
    from df
    """
).show()
// +-----------+
// |customer_id|
// +-----------+
// |  ch_382820|
// +-----------+
```